# I need a python code that will parse a line and get values which I need

Tags: python, regex, scripting

I have line which is similar like line described below

bla bla bla- 3 [saa@dsds aaa="789" SomeName="35229644" vv="typw" ee="o" Task="None"] >bla bla bla

I need a python script which will get a value of SomeName.
It will find 'SomeName' string in the line and write its value:35229644 in some variable

Thanks.

Comment: What code have you written, and what is not working?  We do not volunteer to write code for others.  Please show that you have made an effort to solve your problem.

Comment: At first stage where there was only one string which has a integer value I resolve my problem, here is code
for s in line.split('"'):
                if s.isdigit():
                        ID =int(s)
                        list1.append(ID)
since other strings are added in the line which also have integer values, my code does not work fine. I need to get exactly the value of SomeName

Comment: If it were me, I would use a regular expression to extract the value.

Comment: Yes you are right but the problem is that I don't like that RegEx, but now I understand how powerful are they and that I should learn them :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume that you're new to Python and looking for an example of an approach that might work. I'm also making some assumptions about the format of your lines. Try something like this:

```
import re

def get_some_name(some_name, line):
    regex = r'{0}="([^"]*)"'.format(some_name)
    some_value = re.search(regex, line).groups()[0]
    return some_value

line = 'bla bla bla- 3 [saa@dsds aaa="789" SomeName="35229644" vv="typw" ee="o" Task="None"] >bla bla bla'

print(get_some_name(some_name="SomeName", line=line))
```